# Dyntopo Resolution Seems Off

Tags: sculpting, sculpt, dynamic-topology

So, I'm new to sculpting, and I was following Grant Abbitt's tutorial here: https://youtu.be/lKY2FIy60nc?t=119

His resolution at 20 seems pretty smooth. But, when I try to use that same resolution, mine's completely polygonized. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3D-ETIN6U3A&feature=youtu.be&ab_channel=BehindTheScenes

Is there any reason for this??

Comment: He's probably on a 4k monitor or has some different setup.  I wouldn't worry about it, trust yourself and set it to what makes sense.

Comment: The resolution is based on the size of your brush and how far you are away from the object. To solve this do what @Allen Simpson says.